# composer fails on server with redmine installed

Tags: php, composer-php, redmine

I got a server where I have Redmine 3 installed.

Composer will fail on this mashine:

Install fail (php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php):

```
PHP Warning:  readfile(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in Command line code on line 1
```

If I install it using curl, the install works but once I do my "php composer.phar install" it fails again:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                           
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed                                                  
Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                            
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

This only fails, since Redmine is installed. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with Redmine.

Comment: Maybe this question is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590842/cannot-install-composer-on-mac-os-x/34617315#34617315

Comment: Thanks Gerard, your link was not really related but it made me look into this again. Somehow, the complete directory /usr/lib/ssl was missing on the system. I copied it from another installation, now everything works again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the complete directory /usr/lib/ssl was missing on the system. I copied it from another installation, now everything works again!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: This doesn't change a thing. The only thing this does is to provide a more comfortable way to call composer. Composer will still fail with the same error.